# Formatting strings in Javascript - Translating function from python to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, string

How do you format strings in Javascript? I wrote python code and I'm trying to translate it to javascript but I'm not too sure how

Python code:

```
def conv(t):
    return '%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d' % (
        t / 1000 / 60 / 60,
        t / 1000 / 60 % 60,
        t / 1000 % 60 + 12,
        t % 1000)
```

Does javascript/jquery let you do something similar to this? And if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: this plugin might help http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/jQuery.validator.format#templateargumentargumentN

Comment: I am pretty sure there are libraries that would allow you to do it. Javascript just has string concatenation and other string operations like regex replacement, substring, etc

Comment: You don't really format strings in javascript like that. You have to use a library or extension. Basically you must use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is basically a `printf` / `String.Format`-like operation. Unfortunately, JavaScript currently does not have any built-in way of doing this (which is too bad, really).

There are, of course, many libraries that give this kind of functionality.

[Here's one of them (sprintf)](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) which follows the `printf` syntax, and [here's another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673436/716118) which uses the `format` syntax.

Comment: It looks like printf doesn't let you return the string but only print it? :/ But I'll take a look at number formatting!

Comment: @user2494251: `printf`, originally, yes. But the `sprintf` library actually returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

the closest i could come up with to your python code:

```
   function conv(t){
    t= [ 
        t / 1000 / 60 / 60,
        t / 1000 / 60 % 60,
        t / 1000 % 60 , 
        t % 1000 ].map( Math.floor );

        t[2]=t[2]+"."+( t.pop() + "0000").slice(0,3);

     return t.join(":").replace(/\b(\d)\b/g,"0$1");
   }

//test it out:
new Date(12345678).toISOString().split("T")[1].slice(0,-1); // == 03:25:45.678 
conv(12345678); // == 03:25:45.678
```

pardon if it's not correct, i don't know python, but this seems like what you're trying to do...